# How to pass variable value to socket string

Tags: java, android

I am really new to Android development so this might be a silly question. I am using a firestone database which contains IPaddress and port for a specific user. I am able to get that value into a variable but struggling to pass that value to the socket connection.

I tried to place a public class instead of protected and also follow some guidance on this forum but I think am still not clear on how to fix it.

```
public class DataSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {

    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    PrintWriter printWriter;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

        String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("User").document(currentuser);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        String UIPaddress = document.getString("ipAddress");
                        String uport = document.getString("port");

                    } else {
                        Log.d("LOGGER", "No such document");
                    }
                } 
            }
        });


        String  messg=voids[0];
        try {

            s=new Socket(UIPaddress ,uport );
            printWriter=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(messg);
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Above code throw error Cannot resolve symbol'UIPaddress'. 
Cannot resolve symbol 'uport'.

Comment: Java has nothing what so ever to with JavaScript. Please don't use the JavaScript tag when you really mean Java. Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for that, Updated the code which creates an error "Cannot resolve symbol".

Comment: Dear zoe sorry to say but not sure why you made down vote I though this forum was to gain knowledge I am not technical and just started learning computers my above code was entirely based on my search and people's shared knowledge on this forum only so I did try my best but was not able to resolve the issue therefore I posted question here but looks like by downvoting you are taking away my chance to gain knowledge or help. All I was asking was to point what I am doing wrong. Yes I am not clear about certain concepts of programming because I dont have luxury to attend school like you had

Comment: My lack of knowledge on java vs javascript different should has clearly defined that I am not programmer and you could have explain in simple word and I would have removed the tag instead you choose to analyze me by downvote and gain any help what a world we are in now. But anyways thanks for atlist teaching me that they are two different things I will never forget that now.

Comment: I learned coding online - don't try to guilt trip me again. You're missing one thing for the MCVE (at which point I will retract my close vote and downvote) - the *exact* error. There are 4 symbols in the line you're saying has undefined references, but no mention as to which is unresolved. This isn't a programming concept, this is a fundamental "share what you have, or no one can help", and doesn't apply exclusively to coding. Any answer to the current state of the question will be guesswork, hence the downvote and close vote. Read [ask] for a guide on asking questions

Comment: dear Zoe not sure if you read my question fully but I do have the exact error there is a line below code "s=new Socket(UIPaddress,uport); throw error Cannot resolve symbol." This is the error. Hope this will clarify.

Comment: Let me rephase: cannot resolve *which* symbol? Your comment doesn't clarify anything aside the need for this question to be closed. If you end up fixing the question, feel free to ping me. I've already given you everything you need at this point. Whether you decide to use it, is up to you.

Comment: Zoe i have fixed the error to match what it shows in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to resolve my issue by using the Global variable. Hope this will help other newbie.

```
Socket s;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
PrintWriter printWriter;
public static String uIpaddress ;
public static int uport;
```